# SQL Server stored procedure conversion decimal point without rounding to two decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Decimal point conversion without rounding to two decimal

My variable is of datatype `varchar`, so I have to convert it to numeric. But what the thing is my output value is `0.0012499987` and I want the output as `1.24` i.e. without rounding the value.

This is my code

```
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'CAST((ISNULL(CAST(DI.Coupon AS NUMERIC(18,4)),0) * 100) AS Varchar(50)) AS Coupon,
```

Here I have to multiply with 100 don't remove that; `di.coupon` is of type `varchar`. Keep it in your mind

And the result value also I want as a `varchar`.

Please someone help me

Sample input / output

```
0.013923    1.39
```

Comment: Since it is starting as a varchar anyway, you could always just trim the string to the proper number of places before converting it as well.

Comment: what if you use `NUMERIC(18,2)` ??

Comment: it will convert the varchar to numeric in cast

Comment: who gave the negative vote. just think its not simple because it is in varchar

Comment: But ***why on earth*** are you storing numerical values as `varchar` in the first place?!?! You should *always* use the **most appropriate** datatype - and if it's a numerical value with after-decimal-point digits, then that would be a `DECIMAL(p,s)` - not a `varchar` !

Comment: No . It’s already build by some years ago. So i cant able to change . If i change it will affect all . That’s why i am posted this question

Comment: And it is builded by some one else

Comment: [`Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) takes an optional third parameter that allows you to specify truncation rather than rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CAST

EDIT: I added an ISNULL

```
DECLARE @N

SET @N = '0.013923'

SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(ISNULL (@N, 0) AS DECIMAL(38,18)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS VARCHAR (50))
```

Comment: Ill give u an upvote once I get to 15 but im only at 11 reputation. Seeing as how my answer is a good one and the other one doesnt handle values of variable orders of magnitude then you could just upvote mine

Comment: its super man its work fine.Really works fine man thank you for great help

Comment: Can you give me your mail id. In feature if i have any doubt i can contact you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest is to get the substring of the original column and cast that to numeric. Then it will drop the remaining digits.

In SQL Server, LEFT(column, 4) will do what you want.

But as @HABO pointed out, the in-built function [Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) will accept a parameter that truncates the decimal value.

Comment: i will try and tell @gbj

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for this. This might help for some people

```
cast(left(('00122.45678')*100,instr(('00122.45678')* 100,'.','1')+3)as varchar) as stb
```

Output:

122.456

If you want for 2 decimal without round of then you can add like +2 instead of +3